# Playing chess on a Mac with Stockfish and some GUI

Tags: engines, stockfish

I have a Macbook OS X 10.6 and want to play chess against a challenging program. I'm not very computationally inclined but it seems that I need to download Stockfish and some UCI-compatible GUI. I also want to spend $0 to make this happen. I downloaded Stockfish 231 for Mac and also downloaded pChess 1.9.2 which is reported to have an update that:

Added a wholly new module — pChess.command — copy it into the 'Engines' 
    folder of Sigma Chess or Stockfish, and you can play pChess as a UCI engine!!

I could not find the Engines folder for the Stockfish download that I have. What's more, I'm not even sure what I should do once the pChess.command file is in Stockfish in whatever location is appropriate. When I open the Stockfish-231-mac folder that I have downloaded, the only files are copying.txt (a public licence), logo.bmp, polyglot.ini, readme.txt. The folders are Logos, Mac, and src.

In the readme.txt file:

Stockfish is a free UCI chess engine derived from Glaurung 2.1. It is
not a complete chess program and requires some UCI-compatible GUI
(e.g. XBoard with PolyGlot, eboard, Arena, Sigma Chess, Shredder, Chess
Partner or Fritz) in order to be used comfortably. Read the
documentation for your GUI of choice for information about how to use
Stockfish with it.

I looked through the suggested GUI's and most seem only PC compatible or cost. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a long post on how to do this for latest Macs:

[Chess analysis on Mac Os X Lion 10.7 using Stockfish and HiARCs engine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130219053123/http://fianchetto.org/2012/02/12/chess-analysis-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7-using-stockfish-and-hiarcs-engine/)

Comment: ChessX is what I use. It isn't perfect but it looks better than other free GUIs.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ScidvsMac` which is a fork of `Scid` (Shane's Chess Information Database) with Stockfish. I'm using stockfish as the engine within scidvsmac for analyzing my own games and it's fairly fine. It also has all the typical features of decent gui like variations, opening and ending databases and etc.

Setting it is also very easy. You just need to add stockfish as engine from `Analyze` menu and provide the address to binaries.

### Links:

[Direct link to DMG package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scidvspc/files/mac/ScidvsMac-4.20.dmg/download)

[Homepage of the project](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/)

[Scid for Mac](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30595/scid)

[Original Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/)

[Useful links!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shane%27s_Chess_Information_Database)